# Reading CSV file, match column 3 to column 1 on separate lines

Tags: c#, csv

I am beating my head against the wall, and I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. This can't be as complicated as I'm making it.

I'm working on a project where the program reads one file (that's approx 50 lines or so) and I need to have it match data on the third column to data on the first column of a separate line. I opened up a new project because it was getting too complex for such an easy task.

Here's an example file that is closely relevant to the actual file I'm working with:

`a1,b1,c1,d1
**c4**,b2,c2,d2
a3,b3,c3,d3
a4,b4,**c4**,d4
a5,b5,c4,d5`

I promise this isn't for a school project, this is something that I need to figure out for work purposes.

Here is what I have, and I know it's just not going to work because it's only reading line by line for comparison. How do I get the program to read the current array value in the foreach command against the entire file that I caught in streamreader?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("directories.txt");
        string sline = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] sarray = sline.Split(',');
        string col3 = sarray[2];
        string col1 = sarray[0];
        foreach(string a in sarray)
        {
            // ?!?!?!!!
            // I know this won't work because I'm comparing the same line being read.
            // How in the world can I make this program read col3 of the current line being read against the entire file that was read earlier? 
            if (col3 == col1)
            { 
                Directory.CreateDirectory("DRIVE:\\Location\\" + a.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: use `File.ReadAllLines` and work with the entire collection.  It's not like you have a massive file at 50 lines.

Comment: the commentary portion doesnt disclose whats to be done with the data aside from match it, but you could probably use linq (GroupBy) to find the matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your file is small you can go with the simplest path...

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split(','))
            .ToList();

var result = from a in lines
             from b in lines
             where a[0] == b[2]
             select new { a, b };

foreach(var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", x.a) + " - " + string.Join(",", x.b));
}
```

Comment: Ah man. That was painfully easy, but I learned from it; thank you for your answer!